# How to get component attribute in vuejs?

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to build a drag and drop functionality in my app and to do that I'm using [Muuri](https://haltu.github.io/muuri/) library.

When a user changed the order of the things (skill cards in my case) I need to get the new order and post it to the server. I can get the list of the HTML elements, however I can't access `skillName` attribute on that card (which is also a Vue component).

I don't want to get a specific div and/or innerText of something because it might change in the future, so cleanest solution I can think of is providing an attribute name to the component, and after user changed the positions of the cards, I just get that attribute from that `HTMLElement`.

This is how I create skill-cards in `template` section of the .vue file:

```
.visible-skills
  .visible-skills-item(v-for='value in visibleSkills')
    skill-card(:skillName='value')
```

This is how I initialize Muuri:

```
this.grid = new Muuri('.visible-skills', {
  dragEnabled: true,
  items: null
})
```

This is how I use props in skill-card component (I'm using typescript):

```
class SkillCard extends Vue {
  @Prop() skillName: String
}
```

And this is how I try to access `skillName` attribute:

```
this.grid.on('dragReleaseStart', () => {
  // this.grid.getItems() returns all skill-cards
  let neworder = this.grid.getItems().map((item) => {
    return item.getElement().getAttribute('skillName')
  })
})
```

`item.getElement().getAttribute('skillName')` returns null.

When I `console.log(item.getElement().getAttributeNames())` I can only see `class` and `style`. I think I could see `skillName` too, because isn't it also an attribute?

Comment: Could you please provide working fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little bit of experimenting I managed to add an attribute to the HTML Element from Vue component like this:

```
this.$el.setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue")
```

After doing this, I can access to this attribute from parent element with:

```
item.getElement().getAttribute('attributeName')
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I console.log(item.getElement().getAttributeNames()) I can only
>   see class and style. I think I could see skillName too, because isn't
>   it also an attribute?

No, skillName is a property of the VueComponent and not the same as class or style attribute of an HTML element. I do not understand completely what you are trying to achieve, but is seems you want to access the @Prop skillSet which exist on the SkillCard when an item is dragged into the area.

In this case you would want to emit an event when this happens such as below

```
WhenItemIsAdded() 
{
    this.$emit('dragReleaseStart', someItem);
}
```

Then, the parent component using skill card would have HTML and code similar to below:

```
<template> 
<SkillCard v-on:dragReleaseStart="AddItem"> </SkillCard>
</template>

<script lang="ts"> 
    AddItem(emittedItem) {
      // Do Something With The Item Emitted from the SkillCard
      console.log(emittedItem);
    }
</script>
```